# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing a project with web scraping and I cannot understand why my program refuses to `import bs4`.

I have trouble shooted for hours, tried setting up paths, ensured that wheels was installed, yes I used `pip3`, my `python` and `pip` are both updated, capitalization seems to match others' imports... Can anyone help? Code Excerpt Below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

horse_List = []

horse_List_Soup = []

BASE_URL = 'https://www.horseracingnation.com/horse/' #create a base url to build from

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #user-agent added so that webpage doesn't reject request

def get_Horse_Soup():

     for num in range(len(horse_List)):

        incorrect = True
        while(incorrect):
            response = requests.get(BASE_URL + horse_List[num]) #GET request method with specified url

            if not response.status_code == 200: #catches errors if request is not ok (code 200)
                if response.status.code == 404:
                    raise Exception("Horse not found. Try searching another name.")
                    name = input("Input a new name for rachorse #" + num + ": ")
                    name.replace(" ", "_")
                    horse_List[num] = name
                else:
                    raise Exception("Web request failed. Status Code: " + str(response.status_code))
            else:
                incorrect = False
                horse_List_Soup[num] = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml") 

def main():
   get_Horse_Soup()

main()
```

Traceback Here:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Kisra\Desktop\DataViz_Project\KO_HorseSoup.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: Could you please provide the trackeback that you're getting? That would be helpful in understanding your issue.

Comment: sure, added for you

Comment: Also, for future reference, you can do entire code blocks using triple backticks instead of single ones, which makes it much easier to read.

Comment: If the failure is on line 1, why is all that other code included?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the python kernel you are running your code on is the same that you pip installed bs4. 32 bit python kernel pip packages don't apply to your 64 kernel if you have one and vice versa

Comment: This is a comment rather than answer